# Cannot assign returned function to main variable

Tags: c, string, reverse

The code is the following. It compiles without warnings or errors yet nothing is printed out on the terminal. Any ideas why?

I think the answer must be obvious yet, I cant see it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* palindrome (char *word);

main()
{
    char *leksi, *inverse_leksi;
    //leksi means word
    leksi = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    inverse_leksi = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    
    gets(leksi);
    
    inverse_leksi = palindrome(leksi);
    puts(inverse_leksi);
}

char* palindrome (char *word)
{
    int i;
    char *inverse_word;
    
    inverse_word = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(word) + 1; i++)
    {
        inverse_word[i] = word[strlen(word) - i];
    }
    
    return inverse_word;
}
```

Comment: Don't use gets , please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: It's not true that nothing is printed out. A blank line is printed out, meaning that palindrome returns a zero-length string, or in other words a character array whose first byte is 0. So what does `inverse_word[i] = word[strlen(word) - i];` do if `i` is 0? If you don't know how to answer, use a debugger.

Comment: Also, computing `strlen` every time you execute that loop is painfully inefficient. Do some research into how `strlen` works. The returned value won't change.

Comment: @rici I changed it to `inverse_word[i] = word[strlen(word) -1 - i];` and it worked. I'm new at C so i havent really done any research.

Comment: Do not use `gets` - it is no longer supported as of the C11 standard (it's been a known malware exploit since the late 1980's).  Use [`fgets`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/fgets.html) instead, but be aware that it will store the newline if there's room in the target buffer, so you'll have to account for that.

Comment: @kos: when you're new, you need to do more research :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters in a valid c-style string are in the indexes `0` to `strlen(var) - 1`. The character in the index `strlen(var)` is the null-terminator (`\0`). In the loop you're assigning this character to `invers_word[0]`, so you're returning an empty string. Instead, you should iterate one character less, and then explicitly handle the null-terminator string. Additionally, you have an off-by-one error in the index calculation:

```
// iterate up to the length of the string, without the \0
for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
{
    inverse_word[i] = word[strlen(word) - i - 1];
}
inverse_word[strlen(word)] = '\0'; // explicitly handle \0
```

Comment: It still does not produce an output.

Comment: @Kos You had an off-by-one error in the calculation of the index which I missed. I edited my answer and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `inverse_word[i] = word[strlen(word) - i - 1];`. If you don't have the `-1`, the first character to get copied will be `\0`.

Don't use `gets`. There are better alternatives.